# interact with discord using requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, bots

I'm trying to automate clicking on discord buttons using requests and python, but i have an error when i send the request.

[discord buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tehay.png)

I tried this :

```
header = {
        'authorization' : 'XXX'
}    

data = {
        "type": 3,
        "guild_id": "XXX",
        "channel_id": "XXX",
        "message_id": message['id'],
        "application_id": "XXX",
        "data": {
                "component_type": 2,
                "custom_id": message['components'][0]['components'][1]['custom_id']
        }
}

try:
        r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions', data = data, headers = header)
```

But the program gives me that at the end :

{"code": 50035, "errors": {"data": {"_errors": [{"code": "MODEL_FROM_NON_DICTLIKE", "message": "Models can only be instantiated from something dict-like, got <class 'str'>"}]}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}

If you have any ideas to help me I am interested.
Thanks.

Comment: `"custom_id": message['components'][0]['components'][1]['custom_id']` there's the error

can you print() and print(type()) that?

Comment: message is a string but change data = data to json = data do the job !
Thanks ;)

Comment: Lmao this helped me to finally press buttons! Thx i guess @yurrickx_

Comment: is application_id necessary here? what is it? as i dont see it in messages received from a channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `data = data` to `json = data`

Comment: having same problem. but getting "BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED", "message": "This field is required".    in your code, what is type:3?

Comment: Type I believe is the type of interaction. So whether it is a button, drop down list, etc